# Another flooring identification question

Tags: hardwood-floor

Whatever was used as my living room flooring has a huge range of grain patterns, and I'm wondering what it is. I've tagged this hardwood but that's a guess... Apologies for the odd perspective; pic is upside down but I don't think that matters.
[image: section of living room floor]

Comment: Are you sure it is soft wood looks like oak to me.

Comment: I'm not sure of anything, which is why I'm asking. If it's just a mixture of heartwood and sapwood oak, plainsawn, under a coat of oil varnish, that's believable. I just like the complexity, variation, and non-linear elements, and want to know where to start if I want to match it.

Comment: The look from the photo the grain is tight. If this is T&G oak would be my guess as it lighter than walnut and more brown than cherry, from the T&G floors I have installed if a laminate totally lost, I thought you said soft wood when I read it the first time.

Comment: could be jatoba????

Comment: It is t&g solid wood. (Found that out during some remodeling).  Updated the question to clarify; thanks, @edbeal. Oak is more likely than anything exotic; I'm just not used to seeing this much variation.

Comment: I am glad you mentioned that you like it, I think it is beautiful. I also think it is oak.

Comment: My interior design skills don't go much beyond "can't go wrong with honest wood..." Waiting a bit longer to see if we have any dissenting views.